# Record deleted from DB how do I update UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am deleting the records from a JqGrid using the `Multiselect` option.

```
grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow')
```

Using the above line I get the user selected row ID's and make an ajax call, pass the ID's, and delete them from the DB.

My doubt is after deleting should I re form the grid or what is the best way to handle this?

Any working example would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reload the grid, but that will cause another round-trip the server.

Alternatively, since you already have the ID's the rows you want to delete, you can just loop over that list and  use [`delRowData`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods) method to delete them. This will provide a more responsive solution:

```
var rows = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
rows = rows.slice(); // Create a copy of the array since it
                     // is indirectly modified below
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){
    jQuery('#mygrid').jqGrid('delRowData', rows[i]);
}
```

Comment: Perfectly worked. But only Alternative rows are getting deleted ! i kept a console which returns [1,3,5,7]  only 1,5 getting deleted. Am i doing something wrong with grid ?

Comment: @JustinEthier: `rows` will be **reference** to internal parameter `selarrrow`. After deleting the first item you will compare `i` with `rows.length` which is one smaller. Even if you would cache `rows.length` in another variable it will be wrong because the last half of values `rows[i]` will be `undefined` because `rows` size will be reduced after every deleting. You can for example use always index `i=0` and do this `l = rows.length` times. Alternatively you can just start with `i = rows.length - 1 ` and decrements `i`: `for (var i  = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){...}`

Comment: @user2067567 - Please see my updated answer, it should work for you now.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that as changes happen in the db the grid will be stale you may actually want to reload the grid in order to keep the data from going stale.